# TIKA parsing feedback

Tags: solr, apache-tika

Does a list exist of what types of feedback TIKA can provide about files it cannot parse? I'm trying to decide whether or not to provide end user feedback or feedback for an operations team or both based on what TIKA can tell me. For example if a MS Word document is password protected that is something I could pass back to the end user to take corrective action about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for subclasses of [`TikaException`](http://tika.apache.org/1.2/api/org/apache/tika/exception/TikaException.html) like `ChmParsingException`, `EncryptedDocumentException`, `MimeTypeException` for Tika specific errors...

Signature of `parse()` method of formats parser is

```
Throws:
IOException - if the document stream could not be read
SAXException - if the SAX events could not be processed
TikaException - if the document could not be parsed
```